# Oracle Stored Procedure with undefined number of parameters with Java JSF

Tags: java, oracle, jsf, stored-procedures

I have my JSF form with about **15 checkboxes** and a submit button. I can click all or select only a few checkboxes and then submit the form.

Using a javascript function, i get the checkboxes values i clicked on and concatenate them to a string; for example `checkbox1=IC&checkbox2=S`

This value is sent to my java class.  I want to pass the checkboxes values in a stored procedure in Oracle.

Note that the string can contain values of 1 checkbox to all 15 checkboxes.  The stored procedure should be able to cope with the number of values i get.

**Example:**

`checkbox1=IC&checkbox2=S`  or `checkbox1=IC&checkbox2=S&checkbox3=I&checkbox4=Sa&checkbox5=f&checkbox6=g&checkbox7=h&checkbox8=i&checkbox9=q&checkbox10=e&checkbox11=t&checkbox12=p&checkbox13=89&checkbox14=100&checkbox15=2012`

Any idea on how to write the stored procedure too?

Thanks for your patience and answer.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just pass null values for the boxes that aren't selected, and have the procedure interpret those as necessary? That seems easier on the Java side than named parameters with defaults as you'd have to change the call for each combination. Not sure if I'm missing something though.

Comment: @AlexPoole these checkboxes are dynamic, so the number of checkboxes to be generated are not known in advance

Comment: But you know all the possibilities, right, otherwise how would the proc know what to do with the values? If your proc has 15 parameters, you can just send the values for the boxes you displayed and got values back from?

Comment: You could also send an array of values, or if you don't know the parameters in advance - if the boxes are generated dynamically from table-driven config - an array of pairs of parms/values. Need to see more details of your process to understand what's most suitable, I think.

Comment: Or just pass the string as an argument and tokenize the results of the string on the `&` character in PLSQL?  It would be easier to do the String manipulation in Java though.

Comment: Why are you completely working your way around JSF with ugly JavaScript functions instead of just using standard JSF components to bind the values to the model? Are you sure that you aren't totally missing the point of JSF?

Comment: @BalusC I would be grateful if you could tell what you would do to bind the dynamic checkboxes to my model and how to deal with the stored procedure?

Comment: @AlexPoole which process are you talking about?

Comment: Your question is way too broad. One step at a time. I can answer how to bind the checkboxes to for example a `List<Foo>`. The question of how to store `List<Foo>` in the DB by an Oracle stored prodecude is a completely different one. Do not ask different specific questions in one Question, you won't get fast and good answers.

Comment: @BalusC okay, but am not using a `List` to populate the checkboxes. But i would be glad if you can reply the question of how to store List<Foo> in the DB by an Oracle stored prodecure

Comment: My point is, that you're not binding the checkboxes to a `List<Foo>`, but instead *"Using a javascript function, i get the checkboxes values i clicked on and concatenate them to a string"* is a design problem as you seem to totally miss the point of JSF. It would be a matter of only one component and only two properties. No JavaScript needed. The question of how to store it in DB is a **different** question and completely unrelated to JSF. If you write JSF stuff so that it ends up with a `List<Foo>` and write DB stuff so that it starts with `List<Foo>` you can very easily attach it together.

Comment: @BalusC can you provide an example?

Comment: As said, your question is way too broad. One question per question please. I can't answer the question about the stored procedure. The only person who can answer this broad question is someone who know how to answer the both questions.

Comment: @BalusC Answer the question you can

Comment: Ask a good question first. You've already asked at least [3 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1179713/yash?tab=questions) on the very same subject. None of them received an answer which covers all aspects of the question. Guess why.

Comment: @BalusC maybe i was unclear in my questions but as from now will be more clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the Oracle stored procedure to accept an array.  It's not immediately clear to me exactly how you want to communicate that information to the stored procedure (i.e. do you need to pass the checkbox name and the associated value or do you just need to indicate that checkbox N was checked).  The simplest option to outline (though it may involve more parsing work in the stored procedure) would be to pass an array of strings where each element in the array was something like `checkbox1=IC` to the stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE str_table
    IS TABLE OF varchar2(100);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE process_checkboxes( p_checkboxes IN str_table )
AS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. p_checkboxes.count
  LOOP
    <<do something with p_checkboxes(i)>>
  END LOOP;
END;
```

which you can then call from Java with something like this (adapted from [this askTom thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:712625135727))

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;

public class ArrayDemo
{
   public static void passArray() throws SQLException
   {
       Connection conn = <<get your JDBC connection>>

       String checkboxStr = "checkbox1=IC&checkbox2=S";
       String strArray[] = checkboxStr.split("&");

       ArrayDescriptor descriptor =
         ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( "STR_TABLE", conn );

       ARRAY array_to_pass =
          new ARRAY( descriptor, conn, strArray);

       OraclePreparedStatement ps =
           (OraclePreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement
           ( "begin process_checkboxes(:x); end;" );

       ps.setARRAY( 1, array_to_pass );

       ps.execute();   
   }
}
```

Comment: what is :x? 

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE str_table
    IS TABLE OF varchar2(100);

do i create it in the procedure itself?

Comment: @yeah - You need to create the type in the SQL engine.  It's an object you create in the database before you create the procedure.

Comment: is it possible to split the array in the procedure itself?

Comment: @yeah - If you are asking whether it is possible to send a single string to the stored procedure and then parse the string in the procedure rather than sending an array, that's certainly possible.  But PL/SQL doesn't natively have a function like Java's `SPLIT` so you'd have to write more code and have a less elegant architecture.

Comment: so its better i split the string in java itself and then send it as different arrays and then create the same number of types for the number of arrays i have?

Comment: @yash - Why would you need to create multiple different array types?  Unless there is more that you haven't elaborated on in your question, I would think one array type would be sufficient.

Comment: in fact i want to build my sql statement using the checkboxes, i plan to replace the checkbox1 and so on with actual columns from my database.  These checkboxes can represent 2-3 columns from database

Comment: @yeah - I'm still not sure that I understand why you would need different array types for that.  Presumably, any checkbox name and/or any database column name is representable as a string.  You just need a single nested table type to represent an array of strings.